# how can i execute php code after HTML code

Tags: php, html

i know it's normal for php to execute after HTML but i have a site hosted in both infinityfree.net and  SiteGround.com
the site is working fine on infinityfree.net but it's not working on siteground.com
it turns out that siteground doesn't execute php unless it comes on the top of the page before the HTML code

i don't want to edit my code so if there any trick that i could do i will appreciate the help

here is a sample of the code

```html
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/doc.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
session_start();
 
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}
 
require_once "config.php";
 
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $login_err = "";
 
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "الرجاء ادخال اسم المستخدم.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }
    
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "الرجاء ادخال كلمة المرور.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password, random FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            $param_username = $username;
            
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password, $rand);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            session_start();
                            
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["random"] = $rand;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            
                            
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            $login_err = "اسم المستخدم او كلمة المرور خطأ.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    $login_err = "اسم المستخدم او كلمة المرور خطأ.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "عذراً! حدث خطأ حاول لاحقاً.";
            }

            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
 


</head>    
<body dir="rtl" bgcolor="#073b4c" text="#f1f1f1">
<?php include 'header.html';?>
<style>
.header{
    position:absolute;
}
        .navbar{
            display:none;
        }

</style>
<div class="intro1">     سجل في موقع <b>رأيك فيني</b> وقم بمشاركة الرابط الخاص بك واعرف ما يقوله أصدقاءك عنك 
<br>     عند مشاركة الرابط الخاص بك ستظهر بعض الاسئلة لأصدقاءك ان اختارو الاجابة عنها ستساعدك في تخمين هوية المرسل</div>
 <div class = "vertical"></div>
<div class="text12"><br>ليس لديك حساب؟
<br />
يمكنك المتابعة بحسابك على الفيسبوك او التسجيل في الموقع
</div><br /><br />
<br />
<br /><br />
<a href="register.php"><button class="button">التسجيل</button></a>

    <div class="wrapper">
<div class="wrap">
        <center><font size="+3">تسجيل الدخول</font></center>
        <br />
        <p class="p">ادخل اسم المستخدم الخاص بك وكلمة المرور لتسجيل الدخول.</p>

        <?php 
        if(!empty($login_err)){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $login_err . '</div>';
        }        
        ?>
        <form class="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>اسم المستخدم</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?> f" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>كلمة المرور</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>f">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary f1" value="تسجيل الدخول">
            </div></form></div></div>
<br><br>
</div></body>
```

Comment: try adding `<?php ?>` to the top of the page then or `<?php session_start(); ?>`

Comment: But then remove the duplicated `session_start()` calls from the existing code

Comment: It's throwing errors, most likely, which is why it's failing. `session_start();` must come **before** anything is sent to the browser, so put that at the top of the page. Then check your server error logs for any other errors that would stop your page from working.

Comment: `header("location: welcome.php");` also will not work if you have already output anything.

Comment: i want to know the reason why it works fine on infinityfree.net and it doesn't on siteground.com

i havn't changed anything

Comment: thanks guys for the comments i will take all that in mind